# Intro. Unix: Changing Directories

Tags: unix

I started an online Unix course. I entered the course kinda late and I'm having a little trouble getting caught up. We had a homework question (I got it wrong) it said to:

> Change the current working directory to directory WT5 using a single command line and starting at the ***home path.***

How in the world am I supposed to do that? I know how to change a directory from your current directory just `$ cd WT5` And if I wanted to list all of the contents in the home directory I would use `$ ls ~/nameofhomedirectory` And, if I wanted to change the current working directory to the home directory I would use `$ cd ~` or just `$ cd`

So how would I combine all of that in one single command line to change the current directory to another directory using a path that includes the home directory?

Thank you for all of your help in advance!

UPDATE: Okay. I can see now that this maybe a little confusing. So let me try to make it a little bit more clear where I am going wrong or getting mixed up.

Let's say this is a tree of directories you have. 
[Tree of Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJUp2.gif)

Now, your home directory is *user* And your current working directory is *work* But you want to change your current working directory to *play*. How would you change the directory using a single command line and starting at your *home* direcotry and not your *current working directory **work***

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but you could try:

```
cd ~/WT5
```

or:

```
cd $HOME/WT5
```

or if you absolutely need to be long-winded about it:

```
cd /user/homedirectory/subdirectory/currentworkingdirectory/WT5
```

These all include your home directory in the path. The short-hands are to be preferred.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Dave! Basically I am trying to change the current working directory to another directory named WT5. My command line must contain the home directory in the path. And, it can only be a single line of code. So would I basically use the `cd` command then the name of the home directory then a bunch of slashes as such `cd user/homedirectory/subdirectory/currentworkingdirectory/WT5`

Comment: OK. It would seem you have answered your own question then? What you have written should work (although you need a leading /). It spells out the home directory in full. Hopefully your course will teach you to use the short-hands available for efficiency.

Comment: Oh really? Okay. Thank you so much! I never know if I am right or wrong. My teacher just gives us points for turning in the assignment and doesn't actually give feedback and doesn't teach us this stuff during the sessions. So, I have absolutely know idea if I'm right or wrong. I guess I will learn after our midterm next week. Again Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
cd ~/../users/carol/play
```

The idea is that you can go upwards from a home directory too.